# How to create a text div that overflows from below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, absolute

I'm trying to code this design with `Bootstrap 3.x` but I have a problem with the following `div`.
Suggestions ?

[explanations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPo6Y.jpg)

```css
img{max-width:100%;}
.mydiv{margin-bottom:20px;}
.mytext{
        position: absolute;
        top: 90%;
        right: 50%;
        -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
        transform: translateX(50%);
        width: 70%;
        background-color:#ff0000;
    }
   .myotherdiv{background-color:#00ff00;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-xs-12 mydiv">
              <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" class="mypicture" />
              <div class="mytext">
                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
                 
              </div>
         </div>

         <div class="col-xs-12 myotherdiv">
             My other div text. My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.
         </div>
```

Comment: Your "what I have" is not actually what you have. Please provide us the whole code

Comment: Instead of `position: absolute`, use a negative `margin-top`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using `position` property and to center column you can use `col-md-offset-**`. Below is the snippet for the same

```css
    .center {
      background: skyblue;
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      top: -50px;
    }
    .main{
      border:1px solid red
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/plain-red-blurred-background_1035-3332.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg" style="width:100%;height:50vh">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-4 center text-center">
        <h2>Div1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 main text-center">
      <h1>Other DiV</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question then I think adding a margin-top value to myotherdiv should solve this problem.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.mydiv {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.mytext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  right: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
  transform: translateX(50%);
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.myotherdiv {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  margin-top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-xs-12 mydiv">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260" class="mypicture" />
  <div class="mytext">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
    sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
    tempor invidunt ut labore

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 myotherdiv">
  My other div text. My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.My other div text.
</div>
```

Comment: code snippet is not showing anything. You are missing HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the div class="col-xs-12 mydiv" and the div class="mytext" together, give  a position: relative and then play with the margin-bottom of your wrapper to have the distance you want between the two boxes. Check this code out :

```css
    .mytext{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    right: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%);
    width: 70%;
    }
    .myotherdiv{
    position:relative;
    }
    .wrapper{
    margin-bottom:50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="col-xs-12 mydiv">
          <img src="picture.png" class="mypicture" />
          <div class="mytext">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor                    invidunt ut labore
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-xs-12 myotherdiv">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position:relative` and `position:absolute` properties, with fixed sizes, like that :

```css
.contain{
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
.parent{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
}
.child{
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25%;
}
.other{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 75px;
  background: green;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="parent"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="other"></div>
<p>some text...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, here is my solution :

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center intro">

.mytext{
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 30px;
            transform: translateX(00%);
            margin-top: -60px;
        }
```